# Passing an argument with a range of values into a single-argument python function

Tags: python

I wrote a simple python script to concatenate values from the first row of one dataframe with all rows of another dataframe.

Snippet of one of the dataframes (the second one has identical number of columns):

```
ID Sequence 
1 ATGCCCC
2 GCTCCAC
...
```

My code:

```
...
def mixer(x):
    for row in df1.iterrows():
        fdf["New_ID"]=df1.loc[x, "First_ID"]+df2["Second_ID"]
        fdf["Sequence"]=df1.loc[x, "Sequence"]+df2["Sequence"]
    
    print(fdf)
    
mixer(0)
mixer(1)
mixer(2)
...
```

Currently my first dataframe has only 8 rows but in the future I may have up to a 1000.

**How can I avoid repeatedly calling the function for each value of the argument x** (as you can see at the end of the code snippet)?

I tried using "range" and putting row numbers into a list/tuple and passing it through the function but neither worked.
Would be grateful for your help!

Comment: is `for num in range(10): mixer(num)` what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try:

```
for x in range(num):
    mixer(x)
```

or you could try:

```
num = 1
while num < other_num:
    mixer(num)
```

But this seems so obvius judging by the complexity of your question, so in case this isn't what you were expecting, could you be more specific?